Tabulator version 6.3.0 multiselect headerFilter does not trigger table update after each select
I have a question about a Tabulator headerFilter.
I've updated from v4.9.3 to v6.3.0 and got all the changes worked out, but there's still something I can't figure out.
In table where use headerFilter -> it is a multiselect list of the values ​​in the column.
In version 4.9.3 was headerFilter: "select", now it should become headerFilter: "list" .
In version 4.9.3 when select item from dropdown header filter list the table is updating immediately after each select i have.
Now in version 6.3.0 when select item from dropdown header filter list must click somewhere outside of dropdown to update tables with selected items.
Is there a possibility in version 6.3.0 for the table to update after each selection I make, maybe some custom function for headerFilterFunc.
I would greatly appreciate your help .
In v4.9.3 -> { title: "someTitle", field: "someTitle", headerFilter: "select", headerFilterFunc: "in", headerFilterParams: { values: true, multiselect = true, sortValuesList: "asc" }, width: 520 }
▶️ I made a fiddle for v4.9.3 -> https://jsfiddle.net/chiborator/pjo931sn/46/
In v6.3.0 -> { title: "someTitle", field: "someTitle", editor: "input", headerFilter: "list", headerFilterParams: { valuesLookup: true, multiselect: true }, headerFilterFunc: "in", width: 520 }
▶️  fiddle for v6.3.0 -> https://jsfiddle.net/chiborator/p7ac9b0q/35/
